# Using Jnius to call w3c/Document

Tags: java, python, android, pyjnius

I have a very simple question. I'm trying to use Jnius to call the Document class: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/org/w3c/dom/Document

To do so I've done this:

```
from jnius import autoclass

document=autoclass('org.w3c.dom.Document')
```

So later in my script I can use the document. function (i.e. `document.getElementById()`

However, this returns an exception:

```
jnius.jnius.JavaException: Class not found b'w3c/dom/Document'
```

Am I setting this up correctly?

Edit:

Just wanted to add, I get the same error if I do: `autoclass('org.w3c.dom')`, it still doesn't find the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on the kivy discord was able to answer this. I'll leave this up in case anyone else comes across this issue.

I was using buildozer to compile to apk. To fix the above error you need to add:
`android.gradle_dependencies = org.w3c:dom:2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6` to your .spec file